# Deactivate and Activate Model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to understand how to activate and deactivate a certain Model in rails without necessarily deleting anything.

Came across this code.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 def activate_account!
   update_attribute :is_active, true
 end

 def deactivate_account!
   update_attribute :is_active, false
 end
end
```

I understand for the User model, there is a "is_active" column.

My question is how does this boolean actually cause the object to be activated and deactivated.

I mean is the "is_active" an actually Rails method? or is it defined somewhere else? Can't seem to get how the "magic of activation/deactivation" happens when the column is set to either true or false.

Comment: No magic here. It sets to TRUE or FALSE the attribute `is_active`. So you can know if an user have an `active` account or no with scope or a method. For example : `scope :inactive, -> { where(is_active: false) }` and retrieve all inactive user with `User.all.inactive`.

Comment: the reason why i wish to deactivate a particular model (i.e. Comment) is that I want to hide it, instead of deleting it completely. How do I hide it then?

Comment: You can create similar scope for `active`. And choose to only show `Comment` who are active. `Comment.all.active` in your controller, so `inactive` comments keep in database but are not in your views. You understand the concept behind that ?

Comment: Yes! I finally found the solution. %= render partial: "reviews/review", :collection => @item.reviews.where("active = true"), :as => :review %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on Florrent Ferry's very correct answer, the code you gave as an example are two methods inside the model.

You would call this on your model, for example: `current_user.deactivate_account!` this would call the method on the `current_user`, and update the `is_active` column in their account to `false`.

So, you could achieve something similar with comments, by replicating the methods into your Comment model, and then calling the methods on that particular comment. eg: `@comment.deactivate_comment!` this would set the boolean on that comment to false.

Now, it would still show up if you were using something like `@comments = Comment.all` in your controller, and then looping through `@comments` in your view. Because it still exists, so ALL will pull it out. But, by scoping the `@comments` instance, you can only gather the comments where it active is true.

You can do this directly in the controller using:

```
@comments = Comment.where(is_active: true)
```

But it would be better to scope this as Florrent pointed out. eg, in your model you would set up the scope:

```
scope :active, -> { where(is_active: true) }
```

Then in your controller you can simply call

```
@comment = Comment.all.active
```

Comment: Thanks Florent and abbott567. New to programming. Starting to fall in love with it so deeply. lol.

Comment: @RailsNewbie haha, rails is fantastic for learning programming... So many helpful things it can do for   best of luck with the project